# Help with a proof for the following arguments

Tags: logic, proof

I want to proof the following argument from both sides using the following rules 
 `^I, ^E, vI, vE, →I, →E, ↔I, ↔E, --E, -I`

Argument

```
[(A ↔ B ) → C]         ⊢  [ - ( A ^ B) V C ]
```

Please let me know if my steps are correct, if not please correct me.

```
1) [(A ↔ B ) → C]       A
2) A → B                A
3) B → A                A
4) (A → B) ^ ( B → A )  2,3 ^I
5) A ↔ B                4 ↔I
6) C                    1,5 →E
7) -(A ^ B ) V C        6 VI
```

Now the other side

```
[ - ( A ^ B) V C ]   ⊢   [(A ↔ B ) → C]
```

Here are my steps

```
1) - ( A ^ B) V C ]     A
2) A → B                A
3) B → A                A
4) (A → B) ^ ( B → A )  2,3 ^I
5) A ↔ B                4 ↔I
```

I am stuck at this point, I know I want to get C but I don't know what the next move should be. I hope someone can help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: If you're assuming (2) and (3) in the first proof, then you're not proving [(A ↔ B ) → C] ⊢ [ - ( A ^ B) V C ]. Rather, you are proving [(A ↔ B ) → C] & (A → B) & (B → A) ⊢  [ - ( A ^ B) V C ]. Which one of those sequents are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can prove :

> **[(A ↔ B) → C] ⊢ [¬ (A & B) ∨ C]**

whith the *Law of Excluded Middle* : **⊢ φ ∨ ¬φ**, that is provable from *Double Negation* (or *Rule of Indirect Proof* or *Proof by Contradiction*) : **¬¬φ ⊢ φ**,(¬¬E).

I'll use the *natural deduction* rules of :

- Michael Huth & Mark Ryan, [LOGIC IN COMPUTER SCIENCE : Modelling and Reasoning about Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154310X) (2nd ed 2004), page 27.

---

**(A ↔ B) → C ⊢ ¬ (A & B) ∨ C**

*Proof* :

1) (A ↔ B) → C --- premise

2) C --- assumed

> 3) ¬ (A & B) ∨ C --- from 2) by ∨I

4) ¬ C --- assumed

5) A & B --- assumed [a]

6) A --- from 5) by &E

7) B → A --- from 6) by →I

8) B --- from 5) by &E

9) A → B --- from 8) by →I

10) (A → B) & (B → A) --- from 7) and 9) by &I

11) A ↔ B --- from 10) by ↔I

12) C --- from 11) and 1) by →E

13) ⊥ --- from 4) and 12) by ¬E : **φ, ¬φ ⊢ ⊥**

14) ¬ (A & B) --- from 5) and 13) by ¬I : **if φ ⊢ ⊥, then ⊢ ¬φ**, discharging [a]

> 15) ¬ (A & B) ∨ C --- from 14) by ∨I

Now we have :

> (A ↔ B) → C, C ⊢ ¬ (A & B) ∨ C --- from 2)-3)

and :

> (A ↔ B) → C, ¬ C ⊢ ¬ (A & B) ∨ C --- from 4)-15)

Thus, by *LEM* : **C ∨ ¬C**, we can conclude with :

> > **(A ↔ B) → C  ⊢ ¬ (A & B) ∨ C** by ∨E.

---

---

For : **¬ (A & B) ∨ C ⊢ (A ↔ B) → C**

we cannot prove it, because it is not *valid*.

Assume a *valuation* V such that V(A)=V(B)=V(C)=**f**.

We have that : V(A & B)=**f** and thus V(¬ (A & B) ∨ C)=V(**t** ∨ **f**)=**t**.

But with the above valuation : V(A ↔ B)=**t** and thus V((A ↔ B) → C)=V(**t** → **f**)=**f**.

Thus :

> > **¬ (A & B) ∨ C  ⊭ (A ↔ B) → C**

and so :

> **¬ (A & B) ∨ C  ⊬ (A ↔ B) → C** .

Comment: Isn't step 6 from ^ E on line 5? Also step 7 doesn't seem correct.You don't even have B yet? In addition on step 8, shouldn't that be ^ E on line 5?

Comment: Also you can't really get step 10 unless you have (A → B) ^ (B → A). I don't understand what you mean by step 12. Step 13 is not clear as well. I'm not sure if I can understand this well, it seems like you are using the symbols in a different way.

Comment: @cookiemonster - right, tanks ! coorected the typo into steps 6 and 8. For step 7, it is correct : A ⊢ B → A, for every A, because A → (B → A) is valid (it is a tautology).

Comment: please can you go over your answer again and correct the rest!

Comment: @cookiemonster - in 12 the symbol ⊥ stay for a contradiction : step 4) ¬ C  and step 11) C ; thus, having derived a contradiction, we negate the assumption 5) A & B, getting 13) ¬ (A & B). This can be done with the abbreviation ¬ P := P → ⊥; in this way, deriving a contradiction from  ¬ C, C is nothing else than apply →E to C → ⊥, C in order to derive ⊥. Then, having (A & B) ⊢ ⊥, we derive (A & B) → ⊥, i.e. ¬ (A & B) by →I.

Comment: I think you also made a mistake with step 13, you got it with -I not →I

Comment: I marked your answer for providing more details however I'm not familiar with some of the rules you used so I followed your answer as a guide to come up with similar solution. I end up opening a new one [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/how-to-discharge-an-assumption) to avoid complicating this thread. Please take a look at it and confirm if my steps are valid. I am having problems discharging an assumption, so your help will be appreciated.